# XML parsing with QT

Tags: c++, xml, qt

When we try to parse an xml document with QT, we use something like:

```
QString str;
QXmlStreamAttributes attrib = xml_reader.attributes();
if(attrib.hasAttribute("id"))
{
     str = attrib.value("id").toString();
}
```

To do this, I need to know that the attribute is called "id". Is there a way to read the first attribute without knowing its name?

thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say "the first attribute" what do you mean? The order of attributes is not defined in XML. So you have to determine "the first" using specific condition

Comment: QXmlStreamAttributes is a vector. You should be able to directly index the "first" QXMLStreamAttribute. Again XML does not specify order of attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QXmlStreamAttributes class inherits from `QVector<QXmlStreamAttribute>`. This means that you can "loop" the object just as you would do with QVector

You should be able to access the first item:

```
attrib[0].name();  //containst a QStringRef to the name
attrib[0].value(); //containst a QStringRef to the value
```

By the way it is strongly recommended that you check the QVector size first ;)

```
attrib.size();     //contains the number of attributes
```

Comment: Alternatively, `attrib.begin()->name()` (size check still applies)